# Reports : Using PREVGROUPVAL within a group only

Tags: reporting, opportunity, formula-field, custom-reports, report-formula

I am trying to compute relative expected revenue through months. I am doing this using prevgroupval and it works fine. However, I have to add another level of grouping 'Stage'. With 'stage' being the main grouping I want to show relative values by month for each stage. I am unable to figure out how to get this done. Using prevgroupval as it is picks the value from previous stage when moving from one stage to another.

I hope someone can help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found that changing the report to a matrix report and grouping rows by stage, columns by Close date and using the PREVGROUPVAL to show the summary at both Stage and Close Date allowed me to display data based on PREVGROUPVAL for each stage.